# NoneType error always occurs and I can't remove anything from the tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.config(background="green")
window.bind("<Escape>", quit)
def clogopen():
label = Label(window, bg="green", text="""Changelog:
0.0.1:
    Added title
    Added caps
0.0.2:
    Added Changelog button
    Added Changelog""").grid(row=5, column=0)
    window.after(2000, label.destroy_widget)#this is where I get the error
lab1 = Label(bg="red", fg="white",  text="Welcome to alphabet draw 0.0.2!").grid(rowspan=2, column=0)
cbttn = Checkbutton(text="Caps?").grid(row=3, column=0)
clogbttn = Button(bg="yellow", text="Open Changelog", command=clogopen).grid(row=4,  column=0)
speed(0)
window.mainloop()
```

I am currently adding the basics of the  project, and the changelog is broken.
The error is:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/coding
>   folder/alphabet_draw0.0.3.py", line 14, in clogopen
>       window.after(2000, label.destroy_widget) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy_widget'

Comment: Please include the full error message in your post.

Comment: @glhr Ok. Here's the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

The `grid()` method returns `None`. So, with `label = Label(window, bg="green", text="""...""").grid(row=5, column=0)`, you're essentially setting `label` to `None`, hence the `NoneType` error.

Instead, get the label object first, and apply the grid afterwards:

```
label = Label(window, bg="green", text="""...""")
label.grid(row=5, column=0)
```

And to destroy `label`, use `label.destroy` (not `label.destroy_widget`):

```
window.after(2000, label.destroy)
```

Full code and demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55705699-tkinter-turtle

Comment: Also,  why is the spacing so annoying when it goes onto the screen?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Was your issue resolved?

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as accepted (check mark on the left) since it worked for you.